# C++ using proccesing power/time while console loading bar

Tags: c++, progress-bar, loading

I'm currently new to programming and don't know, how to let the program process while the loading bar is running.
I wanted to display the loading bar and check, wether the program is finished processing. If not, then the processing bar should simply begin to fill again.

My code now is just showing the loading bar once and begins to process after that. This is pretty useless.

I researched on Google and here on stack overflow, but i only got the loading bar from that, not the useful integration in my program.

I just need a simple way to check, wether there would be an output besides the loading bar and i need to run the rest of the program at the same time as the loading bar, just to save time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

static void loading(){
  system("Color 0A");
  cout<<"\t\n\n";
  char a=177, b=219;
  cout<<"\t";
  for (int i=0;i<=50;i++)
  cout<<a;
  cout<<"\r";
  cout<<"\t";
  for (int i=0;i<=50;i++){
   cout<<b;
   for (int j=0;j<=2e7;j++);
  }
  cout << "\n\n";
}

int main(){

//ProjectEuler Problem___

  loading();

  int j=0;
  do{
    j++;
  }while(j<=1e9); //just an example to see when it is processing

  cout << "hi" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The typical pattern you're looking for would look something like:

```
void do_expensive_work(std::atomic<bool>& done) {
  ... something expensive goes here...
  done = true;
}

int main() {
  std::atomic<bool> done = false;
  auto t = std::thread(do_expensive_work, std::ref(done));
  while (!done) {
    ... update your progress bar ...
    ... sleep a bit ...
  }
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

The specifics of how you communicate the result of your computation back to the calling thread etc are up to you. Similarly, you could in theory use a global atomic for the done status, or wrap up the computation in a class that keeps track of state and manages the execution of the thread. Code above is greatly simplified but gives a general pattern.